# Rails route with id after resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, wicked-gem

I have nested routes that I'm having difficulty formatting the way I want to. 
My routes.rb has the following

```
resource :loan_application do
  scope ":loan_application_id" do
    resources :wizard, only: [:show, :update]
  end
end
```

When I click the link to create a new resource:

```
<%= link_to business_loan_application_path(@user), method: :post %>
```

I get sent to a URL that looks like the following

```
http://localhost:3000/businesses/69/163/loan_application/wizard/eligibility
```

For some reason the loan_id (163) comes before /loan_application. I would like it to come after /loan_application.

When I rake routes I can see the same problem:

```
 business_loan_application_wizard GET    /businesses/:business_id/:loan_application_id/loan_application/wizard/:id(.:format) wizard#show
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application I made the routes without your scope:

```
resources :loan_application do
  resources :wizard, only: [:show, :update]
end
```

That leads me into exact the pathes I need

Comment: Making it resources :loan_applications did the trick. If you want to modify the answer I will mark as correct. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's better to read letter by letter ;) I've edit my post, of course it must be resources in the first line. But I'm not quite sure about your _:loan_applications_ , because the there is a difference between loan_application_wizard_path and loan_applications_wizard_path.